# How to use oracle PROCEDURE to get the output in php

Tags: php, sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to call a stored procedure in php from PL/SQL that has both  IN AND OUT parameters. When I try to execute the block below, I get Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-06550: line 11, column 4: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.

PHP CODE :

```
<?php

$sql = 
"DECLARE
    x_emp_number       VARCHAR2(300);
    x_emp_name         VARCHAR2(300);
    x_emp_entiltment   VARCHAR2(300);
    x_emp_job          VARCHAR2(300);
    x_emp_dept         VARCHAR2(300);
    x_emp_bs_group     VARCHAR2(300);

BEGIN
    apps.xx_hrms_custom_mobile.get_emp_detail_info (729,x_emp_number,x_emp_name,x_emp_entiltment,x_emp_job,x_emp_dept,x_emp_bs_group);

END ";

$res1 = oci_parse($link, $sql);

oci_execute($res1);

while ($row = oci_fetch_array($res1)) {
    echo "Completed";
}

exit();
?>
```

this is the procedure

```
 PROCEDURE get_emp_Detail_Info    (p_person_id    IN     NUMBER,
                                x_Emp_Number          OUT VARCHAR2,
                                x_Emp_Name            OUT VARCHAR2,
                                x_Emp_entiltment      OUT VARCHAR2,
                                x_Emp_Job             OUT VARCHAR2,
                                x_Emp_Dept            OUT VARCHAR2,
                                x_Emp_Bs_Group        OUT VARCHAR2);
```

How i get the output value and use it in php ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a semi-colon missing after the END in the PL/SQL block. Try it as:

```
<?php

$sql = 
"DECLARE
    x_emp_number       VARCHAR2(300);
    x_emp_name         VARCHAR2(300);
    x_emp_entiltment   VARCHAR2(300);
    x_emp_job          VARCHAR2(300);
    x_emp_dept         VARCHAR2(300);
    x_emp_bs_group     VARCHAR2(300);

BEGIN
    apps.xx_hrms_custom_mobile.get_emp_detail_info (729,x_emp_number,x_emp_name,x_emp_entiltment,x_emp_job,x_emp_dept,x_emp_bs_group);

END; ";  // Added semi-colon after END

$res1 = oci_parse($link, $sql);

oci_execute($res1);

while ($row = oci_fetch_array($res1)) {
    echo "Completed";
}

exit();
?>
```

Share and enjoy.